# Utilize the Json file in Mulesoft Java class

Tags: java, json, mule

I have a Json file and imported it to my resource folder in mulesoft. I am trying to pass it to mule java class to do some calculations with the values in it. Do i need Json to Object transformer or I can directly pass the Json data to java class? Flow explanation is really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

of course you could pass JSON as string in your custom Java component, but it is more convenient to work with Java objects.

you can use `json-to-object-transformer` to convert your JSON to a generic Java object (java.util.Map) like this:

```
<flow name="flow">
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</flow>
```

now the payload is a instance of `java.util.HashMap` containing the values from your JSON.

if you have a class representing the data in your JSON the replace `java.util.Map` with the fully qualified name of the class and `json-to-object-transformer` will return a instance of this class.

take a look at **"Using the Transformers Explicitly"** here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/native-support-for-json

Comment: The Json file is a Static one. I need to use the json file data inside a Java class to compare and get some values from the json file. how you pass the Json file to Json-to-object transformer?

Comment: it depends... you could use the file connector for example. take a look here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/file-connector

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the JSON file to a `json-to-object-transformer`

you can also use `parse-template` component.